# filter input and isset

Tags: php, input, sanitization

Do i need to filter both `$_GET['action']` and both `$_GET['id']` ??

Normal

```
if (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'delete') {
/* Do Something*/
}
```

Filtered

```
if (isset($_GET['action']) && filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'action',  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) == 'delete') {
    /* Do Something*/
}
```

Normal

```
if (isset($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['id'])) {
/* Do Something*/
}
```

Filtered

```
if (isset($_GET['id']) && !empty(filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT))) {
    /* Do Something*/
}
```

**Edited** Do i need to filter(filter_input) $id or PDO::PARAM_INT do the same thing?

```
if (isset($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['id'])) {

$id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = :id";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

print htmlspecialchars($row['test'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

}
```

Comment: Since its doing nothing but help you remove illegal characters, I see no reason why not to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only check the values, it is not strictly necessary in the sample code you gave.
HOWEVER, it is always a good habit to always sanitize your inputs because you will probably do something with it. Check about the [XSS exploit](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/02/xss-attack-examples/) if you want some example of why it is not a good idea to use your inputs without sanitizing them.

Answer (score 2):

When a GET variable is given as `?foo=` the return of filter is a empty string `''`.
When a `undefined` variable is filtred the return of filter is `NULL`.

When an integer is expected use cast of type to assign a new variable to a private scope, you can validate an ID by this way:

```
$id = intval(filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT));

try {
    if(isValidID($id)) {
        echo $id . ' is OK!';
    }

    // ...
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

function isValidID($id)
{
    if($id == 0 /* you can put more business logic in this test */) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('Invalid value for ID');
    }

    return true;
}
```

Strings, like a name, can be verified by this way:

```
$name = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'name', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

try {
    if(isValidName($name)) {
        echo $name . ' is OK!';
    }

    // ...
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

function isValidName($name)
{
    if(!$name or strlen($name) < 3 or is_numeric($name) /* you can put more business logic in this test */) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('Invalid value for a customer name');
    }

    return true;
}
```

Always filter the input values, also when use PDO. Write your, or find a PHP sanitization library to help you with it.